# What flash slider used in GameSpot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Is there any flash or jQuery headlines slider with images similar to the one used in [Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)... [there](http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html) [are](http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited) [literally](http://pikachoose.com/demo/) [bazillions](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/) [of](http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/) [them](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/).

*(each one of those words is a link to a different jQuery plugin or tutorial that will create something similar to the Gamespot headline scroller, that can be customized with navigation, caption overlay, and autoscrolling if necessary)*